# Retrieve data mysql php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have a live search with two search box that fetches data from mysql database. When I press the submit button I want to show the data of the line in the database that the user has inputed. My problem is that it outputs the different values from the query but only from the second search box and I cannot find why.

Here is my code:

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#button').on('click', function(){
        var smartphone1 = $('#smartphone1').val();
        var smartphone2 = $('#smartphone2').val();
        if ($.trim(smartphone1) != '' && $.trim(smartphone2) != ''){
            $.post('fetchdata.php', {smartphone1: smartphone1, smartphone2: smartphone2}, function(data){
                $('#namedata').text(data);
            });
        }
    });  
});
```

PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['smartphone1']) AND isset($_POST['smartphone2'])) {
    if (empty($_POST['smartphone1']) AND empty($_POST['smartphone2'])) {
        exit();
    }

    $recherche = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'smartphone1', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $recherche = filter_var($recherche, FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);

    $search = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'smartphone2', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $search = filter_var($search, FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);

    require "databasecon.php";

    $mysqli = new mysqli($host_name, $user_name, $password, $database);

    if (!$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT name , capacityingo , ram , prix , photoquality FROM smartphone WHERE name = ?")) {

        $error = array
            (
                'error' => 'The statement could not be prepared'
            );

        echo json_encode($error);
        exit();
    }

    $stmt->bind_param('s', $recherche);
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $search);

    if (!$stmt->execute()) {
        $error = array
            (
                'error' => 'The statement could not be executed'
            );

        echo json_encode($error);
        exit();
    }

    $res = $stmt->get_result();
    $datasmartphone1 = array();
    $datasmartphone2 = array();
    while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc())
    {
        //add each result to an array
        $datasmartphone1[] = $row;
        $datasmartphone2[] = $row;
    }
    //print the array encoded in JSON
    echo json_encode($datasmartphone1);
    echo json_encode($datasmartphone2);    
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Two arrays with same results? What for?

Answer (score 0):

Your query string only has one parameter, that you replace with the first filter and then with the second one.

```
"SELECT name, capacityingo, ram, prix, photoquality FROM smartphone WHERE name = ?"

$stmt->bind_param('s', $recherche);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $search);
```

I think you should change it to

```
"SELECT name, capacityingo, ram, prix, photoquality FROM smartphone WHERE name = ? OR name = ?"
```

or whatever you want to use the second search box value for